# KineticJS enumerate data types of an Object

Tags: javascript, types, kineticjs, enumeration

The code below will enumerate properties of an object, but can the data types be enumerated?

```
function enumerateAttributes(node){
    var text="";
    var attrs=circle1.getAttrs();
    for (key in attrs) {
        if (attrs.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            text+=(key+"=="+attrs[key]+"\n");
        }
    }
    alert(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For javascript data types you can use typeof:  console.log(typeof attrs[key]);

These are some common types that will be returned:

- null,
- undefined,
- object,
- boolean,
- number,
- string,
- function